# How to solve HTTP Web request 500 Internal Server error?

Tags: c#, xml, http, soap, httpwebrequest

Below is my code:

```
 XmlFile = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:auth='http://someurl.com/common/header/auth' xmlns:bal='http://someurl.com/transfer/'><soapenv:Header><auth:authHeader>";
        mssg = XmlFile;
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<auth:username>user</auth:username>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<auth:password>pw</auth:password>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "</auth:authHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<bal:DebitRequest>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<bal:MSISDN>" + MSISDN + "</bal:MSISDN>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<bal:debitAmount>" + Amount + "</bal:debitAmount>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "<bal:reason>FIMOBILE</bal:reason>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "</bal:DebitRequest>";
        XmlFile = XmlFile + "</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://url");
        myWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
        byte[] chargeRequestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XmlFile);
        myWebRequest.ContentLength = chargeRequestBytes.Length;
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://api.tunetalk.net/infinet/BalanceManagement");
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("username", "user");
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("password", "pw");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(XmlFile);
        writer.Close();

        // Send the 'WebRequest' and wait for response.
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);

        HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

After the last line it is throwing error:

```
 500:Internal Server Error
```

I am quite new in SOAP I would appreciate most if somebody help me to figure this out. Thank you.

UPDATE:

Actually there is a vb.net script for the same code is available in another project which is working perfectly. So, my task was to convert from vb.net to c# but after converting it is not working.

Here is the original VB.Net code from where I have converted my C#:

```
  XmlFile = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:auth=""http://someurl/header/auth"" xmlns:bal=""http://someurl""><soapenv:Header><auth:authHeader>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<auth:username>user</auth:username>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<auth:password>pass</auth:password>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "</auth:authHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<bal:DebitRequest>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<bal:MSISDN>" & checkMSISDN & "</bal:MSISDN>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<bal:debitAmount>" & debitAmount & "</bal:debitAmount>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "<bal:reason>FIMOBILE</bal:reason>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "</bal:DebitRequest>"
        XmlFile = XmlFile & "</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"

        Dim myWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://someurl")
        myWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
        myWebRequest.ContentLength = XmlFile.Length
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://api.tunetalk.net/infinet/BalanceManagement")
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("username", "user")
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("password", "pass")

        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(myWebRequest.GetRequestStream)
        writer.Write(XmlFile)
        writer.Close()

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
        Dim myWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
```

Comment: Without having access to the web service's site to turn on enhanced error messages, there's not much you can do.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Will you please suggest me whether I did mistake on my XML?

Comment: The structure of the SOAP body will be dependent on what the service is requiring.  Do you have any documentation on the web service?

Comment: no I don't have any information regarding the web service. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Actually I have converted this code from a VB.Net script which is currently working and with the same web service. If you like to have a look at that please check my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Many times the service will give you some documentation and ways to test.  Just go to the service URL.  (Sorry, I won't...it's a self-signed SSL cert...not going to trust that site.)

Comment: If you can still run the VB.NET version, then fire up WireShark (set your filter to "http") and look at the difference between what the two applications are sending.

Comment: Also, why convert the string to bytes to get the content length instead of just using XmlFile.Length as was done in VB?

Comment: so sorry I don't have enough experience on SOAP or web service so I am not so familiar with WireShark.

Comment: Yes I have tried with XmlFile.Length before but same error so later I have changed this.

Comment: WireShark is not specific to SOAP or web services.  It's a utility to monitor traffic in/out of the system.  If you set the filter to "http" it will just monitor the HTTP traffic and allow you to look at the payload.  This will allow you to compare what VB sends to what C# sends.  Once you see the difference, then you'll know what to change.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated information, there has to be some fine error in your conversion.  Nothing stands out to me so it could just be some minor typo.

My suggestion is to run WireShark and set your filter to "http" to monitor only HTTP traffic.  Then, run both programs and compare the data sent to the web service.

You could also *try* using Fiddler2 instead.  It's simpler to use and allows more interactive processing with the remote endpoint.  However, I have found that in certain cases it won't work with the client because the client may not respect the system proxy settings and attempt to go direct.

If you're going to be writing code to go to web services, these are two tools that you should have installed for debugging.  You should also study up on web services and the technologies that you're going to use.  These technologies are not difficult and you should be able to get enough knowledge on them fairly quick.